# How can I log out from a board that I’ve signed in before?

Tags: trello

I've subscribed to a working group last year but now on I am no longer a part of it so I don’t want to see that board in my account.

How can I log out from a board that I’ve subscribed before?

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the board's name that you want to unsubscribe from and unselect "Subscribe". The page should refresh and you will no longer be subscribed to the board.