# How can I get a board off of my list that I've been added to by another Admin?

Tags: trello

A previous question asks [How can I log out from a board that I’ve subscribed before?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/34040/how-can-i-log-out-from-a-board-that-ive-signed-in-before)

Now I have a similar question: How can I get a board off of my board list that I've been added to by another Admin. I'm not subscribed, but I can't delete/archive or hide it. I asked for the Admin to remove me, but I have had no response.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove yourself from the board; you don't need the admin to do it for you. Click your avatar in the member section, then choose "Leave Board..."

[image: Leave Board...]